# Disable other programs intercepting key combinations

Tags: vb.net, hotkeys

I'm creating a hotkey program in VB.NET, which can detect a key combination from a different program, and type in a string. I am using global hotkeys to detect the key press, however some applications intercept key presses, and prevent them from reaching my program. For example, in Chrome, pressing CTRL + T will open a new tab. Also, and this happens in windows as a whole, some key combinations (such as CTRL + ALT + A) type a different key (á, in this case).

I need to prevent this.

My code currently looks like this:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class Form1
    Public Const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    Dim currentNum As Integer = 0

#Region "Hotkey stuff"
    Public Const MOD_NONE As Integer = &H0
    Public Const MOD_ALT As Integer = &H1
    Public Const MOD_CTRL As Integer = &H2
    Public Const MOD_CTRL_ALT As Integer = &H3
    Public Const MOD_SHIFT As Integer = &H4
    Public Const MOD_CTRL_SHIFT As Integer = &H6
    Public Const MOD_CTRL_ALT_SHIFT As Integer = &H7

    Public Const WM_HOTKEY As Integer = &H312

    <DllImport("User32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function RegisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr,
                        ByVal id As Integer, ByVal fsModifiers As Integer,
                        ByVal vk As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    <DllImport("User32.dll")>
    Public Shared Function UnregisterHotKey(ByVal hwnd As IntPtr,
                        ByVal id As Integer) As Integer
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        If m.Msg = WM_HOTKEY Then
            Dim id As IntPtr = m.WParam
            Select Case (id.ToString)
                Case "1"
                    SendKeys.Send("Test")
            End Select
        End If
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub
#End Region

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ComboBox1.SelectedItem = ComboBox1.Items.Item(0)
        ComboBox2.SelectedItem = ComboBox2.Items.Item(0)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click


        If ComboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            MsgBox("Please select a key.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
        currentNum += 1
        RegisterHotKey(Me.Handle, currentNum, getModKeyCode(ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString), getKeyCode(ComboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString))
    End Sub

    Function getKeyCode(keyText As String)
        If alphabet.Contains(keyText) Then
            Return Asc(keyText) - 32
        ElseIf IsNumeric(keyText) Then
            Return CInt(keyText) + 48
        ElseIf keyText.StartsWith("F") Then
            Return CInt(keyText.Remove(0, 1)) + 111
        ElseIf "[]#;',./\|*-+=".Contains(keyText) Then
            If keyText = "[" Then
                Return 219
            ElseIf keyText = "\" Then
                Return 220
            ElseIf keyText = "]" Then
                Return 221
            End If
        End If
        Return Keys.A
    End Function

    Function getModKeyCode(modText As String)
        If modText = "CTRL" Then
            Return MOD_CTRL
        ElseIf Text = "ALT" Then
            Return MOD_ALT
        ElseIf modText = "SHIFT" Then
            Return MOD_SHIFT
        ElseIf modText = "CTRL + ALT" Then
            Return MOD_CTRL_ALT
        ElseIf modText = "CTRL + SHIFT" Then
            Return MOD_CTRL_SHIFT
        ElseIf modText = "CTRL + ALT + SHIFT" Then
            Return MOD_CTRL_ALT_SHIFT
        Else
            Return MOD_NONE
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: That's probably going to require some [low level keyboard hooks](https://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/11087_2193301_3/Managing-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hooks-in-VB-NET.htm).